# Split file with pattern and use pattern as file names

Tags: perl, unix, awk

File contain data like below

```
  <p> 21-01-72  XXXXX YYYY ZZZZ</p>

  <p>Line Data XX YY ZZ</p>
  <p>Line Data XX YY ZZ</p>
  <p>Line Data XX YY ZZ</p>

  <p> 22-01-72  XXXXX YYYY ZZZZ</p>

  <p>Line Data XX YY ZZ</p>
  <p>Line Data XX YY ZZ</p>
  <p>Line Data XX YY ZZ</p>

  <p> 23-01-72  XXXXX YYYY ZZZZ</p>

  <p>Line Data XX YY ZZ</p>
  <p>Line Data XX YY ZZ</p>
  <p>Line Data XX YY ZZ</p>
```

Used below command to split into multiple files where first line becomes file name

```
awk '/-72/{gsub(/<p> /,""); gsub("</p>",""); gsub(" ",""); fname=$0".dat"; next} {print > fname}' data.xml
```

Got 3 files created with data

```
  <p>Line Data XX YY ZZ</p>
  <p>Line Data XX YY ZZ</p>
  <p>Line Data XX YY ZZ</p>
```

Now, all new files needs to append with `<article>` in beginning and `</article>` in the end. How we can do it in the same awk command? or it is better to use separate commands later?

Required file with data

```
<article>
  <p>Line Data XX YY ZZ</p>
  <p>Line Data XX YY ZZ</p>
  <p>Line Data XX YY ZZ</p>
</article>
```

Comment: Voted to reopen, since (reasonable?) code has been added, with a statement on what it produces and what is wanted.  @Rv555 -- in the future, please always include what you tried and what it did or didn't do.

Answer (score 1):

This `gnu awk` should do:

```
awk -F"[ <]+" '/<p> ([0-9][0-9]-){2}[0-9][0-9]/ {f=$3" "$4" "$5" "$6} {print >f ".txt"}' file

cat "21-01-72 XXXXX YYYY ZZZZ.txt"
  <p> 21-01-72  XXXXX YYYY ZZZZ</p>

  <p>Line Data XX YY ZZ</p>
  <p>Line Data XX YY ZZ</p>
  <p>Line Data XX YY ZZ</p>

cat "22-01-72 XXXXX YYYY ZZZZ.txt"
  <p> 22-01-72  XXXXX YYYY ZZZZ</p>

  <p>Line Data XX YY ZZ</p>
  <p>Line Data XX YY ZZ</p>
  <p>Line Data XX YY ZZ</p>
```

It will search for date section and use that as a file name.

Comment: You should mention that's relying on undefined behavior (unparenthesized expression on the right side of input/output redirection) so it'll do different things in different awks. It'll also fail in all awks except gawk after creating about 15 output files with the "Too many open files" error. If I were you I'd just say "Using gawk..." up front!